# How to make pattern matching for multiple dataframes with reference column ID in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have parent query data.frame with 403 rows and 5 columns where I am gonna use its `NUTS_ID` and `NUTS_NAME` as reference columns to filter the data in target data.frames (427 rows and 7 columns), please take a look [example data snippets on the fly](http://jmp.sh/nrDSf8Q). To do so, I tried `base::match` to get common rows in target data.frame by using `code` columns in query data.frame, but it is not efficient because the pattern is not consistent.

Here is head of query data.frame:

```
> query_df
     CNTR_CODE   FID LEVL_CODE NUTS_ID                  NUTS_NAME
  1:        DE DEF0D         3   DEF0D                   Segeberg
  2:        DE DEF0E         3   DEF0E                  Steinburg
  3:        DE DEF0F         3   DEF0F                   Stormarn
  4:        DE DEG01         3   DEG01   Erfurt, Kreisfreie Stadt
  5:        DE DE119         3   DE119             Hohenlohekreis
 ---                                                             
398:        DE DEG0K         3   DEG0K           Saale-Orla-Kreis
399:        DE DEG0L         3   DEG0L                      Greiz
400:        DE DEG0M         3   DEG0M           Altenburger Land
401:        DE DEG0N         3   DEG0N Eisenach, Kreisfreie Stadt
402:        DE DEG0P         3   DEG0P              Wartburgkreis
```

Here is snippets of target data.frames:

```
> target_df
     Country                       Name
  1:   de111      Stuttgart, Stadtkreis
  2:   de112                  Böblingen
  3:   de113                  Esslingen
  4:   de114                  Göppingen
  5:   de115                Ludwigsburg
 ---                                   
423:   deg0k           Saale-Orla-Kreis
424:   deg0l                      Greiz
425:   deg0m           Altenburger Land
426:   deg0n Eisenach, Kreisfreie Stadt
427:   deg0p              Wartburgkreis
```

Here is my attempt to read the [example data snippets on the fly](http://jmp.sh/nrDSf8Q):

```
library(openxlsx)
query_df <- read.xlsx("example_data_snippets.xlsx", sheet = 1)
target_df1 <- read.xlsx('example_data_snippets.xlsx', sheet = 2)
```

for filtering data in target data.frame by using reference column key in query data.frame, I simply tried as follow:

```
target_df1[match(query_df$NUTS_ID, target_df$Country),]
```

but this gave me error, perhaps my above attempt can't deal with upper case code and lower case for matching.

**desired output**:

in my desired output, filtered data.frame can have same code, `NUTS_ID` by finding matching.

How can I optimize my above solution? Is there any efficient way to filter the data in multiple data.frames by using reference column in query data.frame? Is there any efficient utilities in `dplyr` or `data.table`? Is there any efficient way to make this happen? Any idea?

Comment: Look for merge / joins. Read this [SO post](/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: I can join the tables together when I to a toupper(Country). `target_df1 %>% mutate(Country = toupper(Country)) %>%  inner_join(query_df, by = c("Country" = "NUTS_ID"))`. Not sure what your desired output is, but this returns 357 records out of 427 in target_df. Also `semi_join` would return only the data from target_df without columns from query_df.

Comment: @phiver one more question, is that possible to extend your solution for dealing with multiple data.frame/worksheets? I mean looping through multiple target data.frame for checking patterns. Is that doable? Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean joining all the sheets together? Or using query_df and joining it to sheet2, then to sheet3 and then to sheet4, so you end up with 3 data.frames? Btw your data looks as if it resides in a database. You might want to perform your actions on the data.base.

Comment: @phiver I mean using loop `lapply` to find pattern matching for each worksheet. Is that doable? Any possible extension for your solution? Thank you

Comment: Check the answer, is that what you would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `readxl` instead of `openxlsx`; that is just a matter of preference. Using toupper on country to be able to join the tables together.

```
library(readxl)

query_df <- read_excel("example_data_snippets.xlsx", sheet = 1)
target_df1 <- read_excel('example_data_snippets.xlsx', sheet = 2)


target_df1 %>% 
  mutate(Country = toupper(Country)) %>% 
  inner_join(query_df, by = c("Country" = "NUTS_ID"))
# A tibble: 357 x 12
```

Or if the data from query_df is not needed a semi_join can be used.

```
target_df1 %>% 
  mutate(Country = toupper(Country)) %>% 
  semi_join(query_df, by = c("Country" = "NUTS_ID"))
# A tibble: 357 x 8
```

load all files in 1 resulting list:

```
query_df <- read_excel("example_data_snippets.xlsx", sheet = 1)
target_df1 <- read_excel('example_data_snippets.xlsx', sheet = 2)
# need to skip first line :-( otherwise could automate reading in all sheets in one go.
target_df2 <- read_excel('example_data_snippets.xlsx', sheet = 3, skip = 1)
target_df3 <- read_excel('example_data_snippets.xlsx', sheet = 4, skip = 1)

#set nuts_id to lower so it matches all the Country names in the other sheets.
query_df$NUTS_ID <- tolower(query_df$NUTS_ID)     


result <- lapply(list(target_df1, target_df2, target_df3), function(x) inner_join(query_df, x, by = c("NUTS_ID" = "Country")))
```